# /home partition doesn't seem to be mounted in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, mount, gparted

After some difficulties dualbooting Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10, I've noticed that my /home partition isn't mounted. How would I go about mounting it. I though about using the built in Disks program, and changing the mounting point, but I don't want to mess with something I don't fully understand.

[image: Here's a GParted screenshot]

My system's installed on /dev/sda7, and my home partition was supposed to be /dev/sda9

cat -n /etc/fstab yields:

```
 1  # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
 2  #
 3  # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
 4  # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
 5  # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
 6  #
 7  # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 8  # / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
 9  UUID=332e4fb1-3da1-43cb-b158-0dbdb8887bc7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
10  # /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
11  UUID=98DD-02CA  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
12  /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sudo blkid:

> /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="98DD-02CA" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="M-bM-^MM-(M-CM-8" PARTUUID="7e18bfc7-7115-469d-b722-7e80db8155b8"
>   /dev/sda3: UUID="01D3A8477E4D35D0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="4482f98a-1b98-4fcb-bf67-4f0dc973d1af"
>   /dev/sda4: UUID="9CEE3032EE3006D4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="9b075908-0490-4e45-bdd8-4e3ecc895b74"
>   /dev/sda5: UUID="96DA05C7DA05A499" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="\"" PARTUUID="73b356fb-4440-483b-b58c-2ea3ca8cd3db"
>   /dev/sda6: LABEL="WINRETOOLS" UUID="B00827F30827B76E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="M-jM-=M-^TM-WM-^IM-hM-)M-^PM-IM--" PARTUUID="a6c7aa22-508b-4a31-8470-873ca170fd18"
>   /dev/sda7: UUID="332e4fb1-3da1-43cb-b158-0dbdb8887bc7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="754ea8a9-ccc1-4d19-95ce-9419cc072051"
>   /dev/sda8: UUID="53f4d8c7-7344-4c7e-b4d9-7f547e5d598d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0dcf2301-0ebc-4f6e-aa8a-9fef96063523"
>   /dev/sda9: UUID="28caf3ca-ee0a-4a5a-b26c-4cc64afd858d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4d2f23bf-69a1-4bad-8b64-59ba843bdbe0"
>   /dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
>   /dev/sda2: PARTUUID="af660048-4afc-4e30-a581-971e43bd3d7a"

lsblk -f:

> NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL      UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
>   loop0  squashfs                                                 /snap/canonical-livepatch/50
>   loop1  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-logs/37
>   loop2  squashfs                                                 /snap/ruby/113
>   loop3  squashfs                                                 /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
>   loop4  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-logs/45
>   loop5  squashfs                                                 /snap/discord/82
>   loop6  squashfs                                                 /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
>   loop7  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
>   loop8  squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-characters/103
>   loop9  squashfs                                                 /snap/core/6034
>   loop10 squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
>   loop11 squashfs                                                 /snap/canonical-livepatch/54
>   loop12 squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
>   loop13 squashfs                                                 /snap/core/4917
>   loop14 squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-calculator/180
>   loop15 squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-characters/139
>   loop16 squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-calculator/260
>   loop17 squashfs                                                 /snap/core/6130
>   loop18 squashfs                                                 /snap/discord/84
>   loop19 squashfs                                                 /snap/spotify/30
>   loop20 squashfs                                                 /snap/postman/81
>   loop21 squashfs                                                 /snap/postman/80
>   loop22 squashfs                                                 /snap/spotify/28
>   loop23 squashfs                                                 /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
>   loop24 squashfs                                                 /snap/discord/86
>   sda
>   ├─sda1 vfat     ESP        98DD-02CA                            /boot/efi
>   ├─sda2
>   ├─sda3 ntfs                01D3A8477E4D35D0
>   ├─sda4 ntfs                9CEE3032EE3006D4
>   ├─sda5 ntfs                96DA05C7DA05A499
>   ├─sda6 ntfs     WINRETOOLS B00827F30827B76E
>   ├─sda7 ext4                332e4fb1-3da1-43cb-b158-0dbdb8887bc7 /
>   ├─sda8 swap                53f4d8c7-7344-4c7e-b4d9-7f547e5d598d 
>   └─sda9 ext4                28caf3ca-ee0a-4a5a-b26c-4cc64afd858d

Comment: Please run `cat -n /etc/fstab` and add that to your question!

Comment: I added it! I tried following Vijay's advice, however, I was unable to locate /dev/sda9's UUID

Comment: Please post the result of the commands `sudo blkid` and `lsblk -f` into your question

Comment: I've added the requested files!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find UUID of sda9 by

command:

```
sudo blkid
```

and then open fstab file by command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

add this line below the line for swap entry.

```
UUID=xxxx       /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

replace xxxx  by the UUID of sda9.

Test with

```
sudo mount -a
```

and reboot

- You can do it through "Disks" also.

Comment: I wasn't able to find sda9's UUID in /etc/fstab. I've included what was in /etc/fstab in the problem description.

Comment: Confirm with `sudo blkid`.

Comment: Try it before you reboot with `sudo mount -a`. Testing here can prevent a typo causing a boot failure.

Comment: I misread your instructions, I apologize. Trying again now

Comment: It worked! Thank you! There was some data on the old partition's /home directory, however. How would I access it, if I still can? If not, it's not that big of a loss. It was my fault for not properly backing up those files anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well , in your fstab you need an entry like:

```
UUID=28caf3ca-ee0a-4a5a-b26c-4cc64afd858d /home        ext4      defaults      0 2
```

this should do it if that UUID is in fact what you want it to be.